# What causes a server to block internet access

Tags: linux, centos, internet

I am running an API on a server. A customer is polling the server with API requests 8-10 times per second. I know this is bad practice and I am working on getting the customer to change. But in the meantime, after a while the server blocks internet access. I cannot see outside my internal lan and I cannot see it from the outside world. It is running, and I can ssh in from another server on my internal network. I restart apache and that doesn't help. Rebooting always fixes it so I assume it is not the firewall. It looks like something is detecting an attempted DDOS attack and turning off internet outside access.

The server is running Centos 7 with all the most recent patches and upgrades. I am fixing this the right way by throttling API access but I want to understand what is happening internally. Is there a utility that runs as part of Centos default that does this?

Thanks for any insight. Here is a snippet from my access logs...you can see that he is hitting us 8 times per second.

```
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:47:59 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /pwi HTTP/1.0" 200 165 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:00 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /measurements HTTP/1.0" 200 67 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /auth HTTP/1.0" 200 215 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
xx.73.83.167 - - [25/Jun/2019:13:48:01 -0700] "POST /pwi HTTP/1.0" 200 165 "-" "Java/11.0.3"
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

It has happened three more times. When I try to go to the server with a browser, I get server not found errors. I can shell into the server through my internal network. Everything is running. Ports are open in firewalld. I restart apache, No help. I restart firewalld, not help. I reboot, everything gets fixed. Some process somewhere block external internet access. I assume that since rebooting work it cannot be the external switch, or firewall? The VMs are VMware so they are running a NIC pool so other systems would also experience this if it were a NIC issue? What other logs can I check? Someone suggested dmesg but the output is verbose and coded. I don't know what to look for. Any ideas what to check next? I am building a new VM and will migrate to that, but I really want to now what causes this. One other thing .. this machine has been running fine for three years. I have applied all updates so the server is current.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: As I said, it can;t be the firewall because rebooting the server fixes it and that has no effect on the firewall. But I did check and when I nmap from another internal server, only port 22 is still open. So something in Centos 7 is detecting an anomaly and closing ports. Rebooting opens them.

Comment: Apparently I missed a few words. You need to check the firewall while the problem is happening. This does indeed sound like something is adding firewall rules (which of course disappear when the instance is restarted).

Comment: You're talking about the internal firewall, firewalld, not the external firewall, right? So are there triggers that set firewalld rules automatically? Well, I'll google it. of course.

Comment: YES! It happened this morning and firewalld definitely had 80 and 443 turned off. So how do I determine what is causing that?

Comment: Nothing that is shipped with the system would do that. Look for local customizations made by another admin or by third party software.

Comment: Turns out firewalld is not affected. It just happened again. Internal network is fine. All ports that are supposed to be open are. Apache is running. But the outside world sees 'server not found'. Rebooting fixes it. I am lost as to what to check next?

Comment: Check for a `fail2ban` on the server, or any kind of DoS/DDoS prevention in the network or on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to test out with a small SOHO router if you can or remove DPI from your router.

As it work in the LAN and not via the WAN please know that some enterprise class router do DPI, deep packet inspection, and can have difficulty when large number of traffic passtru them.

I had similar issue with a old Cisco ASA and the mail server of a customer that was dropping randomly some incoming emails.

The fact you restart and the trouble go away is easy to explain, as the server no longer accept anything and it unload indirectly the router

Comment: So even if it is an external firewall issue rebooting my vm can clear it?

Comment: @DougWolfgram While the server reboot, does the server handle request ? No, so yes, it help to unload the router, but it's a temporary fix as you guess it. The most important there in your diagnostic step is that it does not work from the WAN while it still work from the LAN

Answer (score 1):

Steps to troubleshoot your issue:

- Run the `tcpdump` and check the traffic.
- Do you see incoming `TCP-SYN` packets? If don't or you see incoming `TCP-SYN` packets and repeated sent `TCP-SYN-ACK` - check a network device before your server.
- You see incoming `TCP-SYN` packets, but don't see any replies. Check the firewall with `iptables-save -c`. The order of rules is very important. Do you use the fail2ban? Also check the routes with `ip route get <server-ip> from <client-ip> iif <iface>`  and `ip route get <dst> from <server-ip>` commands. It must show valid routes.
- Issue can be caused by overflow of the conntrack table. Check output of `dmesg` and `conntrack -S`.
- Issue can be caused by exceeding of limit of opened sockets (usually it's half-closed sockets). Use `ss` and `nstat` to check it.
- Carefully investigate output of `nstat -az` command. It lists a huge number of metrics and error counters.
- Increase the logging of server. Check error logs. Next step of troubleshooting is usage of the `strace` tool to trace the syscall executions.

Comment: New data: The server went down again. Well, to be truthful, it is a new server. I left the old server that was having problems running and changed it's IP to .104. Production code is running on there and appears to be fine. The new server is at the OLD IP address and after 2 days, went down. Even though there is nearly no traffic on it. It is just a dev and demo server which no-one except me is using for now.  I am not sure how to interpret the output of these utilities. I do use fail2ban. But a status check says the same ports (22, 80 and 443) are open. It is WAN access that is blocked.

Comment: If you doubt about interpretation of output, just copy it into the question. I'll extend the answer. Have you run the tcpdump? What did you see in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Some instructions for troubleshutting:

Run **netstat** to see the connections and the process that are attached to each socket:

```
sudo netstat -nlpt
```

Check that the process corresponds to what you think should be listening and serving (Apache)

Check system limits with ulimit, to see if the maximum number of processes has been reached:

```
ulimit -a
```

Try to access the webserver from localhost (your ssh session), use **wget** or curl.

Review memory, cpu and syslog. Use **top**  for the first to and tail -f /var/log/syslog or the corresponding command in your system. Do it just after reboot and  while accessing the web server.

Comment: Netstat shows the ports open that I'd expect.

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5486/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5482/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5486/httpd

Comment: Top looks like nothing is happening. it is down right now. No CPU usage at all. Service is running fine but it looks like apache is down. I restart apache and it has no effect. Only rebooting helps.